# A riddle to fiddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Always getting closer,
But never close enough
And when the day is over
From a second away, to an entire day,
Catching me is more than tough

However hard you try, I reckon
You won't ever catch me
Nearing every passing second
Try as you might, we won't unite
The wait infinite, you'll never catch me*

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you:

> Tomorrow

**Reasoning:**

Always getting closer,

> Tomorrow is always getting closer

But never close enough

> Often you are really looking forward to a tomorrow

And when the day is over
From a second away, to an entire day,

> At 11:59.59 tomorrow is a second away but then at 12:00 it's a day away

Catching me is more than tough

> You can never be in tomorrow

However hard you try, I reckon
You won't ever catch me

> Same as last lines

Nearing every passing second

> Tomorrow is always getting closer

Try as you might, we won't unite
The wait infinite, you'll never catch me

> Again same reasoning you can never be in tomorrow

Comment: This is correct! Nice explanation as well, an all round perfect answer

Comment: Great, now the song from Annie is stuck in my head.